# Having a function return a true of false bool

Tags: python, function, boolean

Im new to python and I cannot figure this out. Here is what I am trying to do:

I am trying to write a function that takes a string as an argument and checks if the string only contains the digits 5 and 6. If it does, then return the Boolean True. If it doesn't, return the Boolean False. Example of function: numberCheck(string).

I know this is very simple for some people, I just cannot figure out the logic on it yet.

Comment: If this is a learning exercise, us just saying ``set(string) <= {*"56"}`` probably isn't going to help much. What have you tried so far? What are you struggling with?

Comment: Hi! We're not a code writing service, but we'd love to help once you run into a problem. Show us what you've done so far!

Comment: This is probably not at all correct but what I have tried is this: def numberCheck(string):
        return bool([string== 5 | 6])

Comment: If you as a human being had to determine if a string of numbers was all 5s and 6s, what process do you imagine that might entail?

Answer (score 2):

You can use python [sets](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets).

They have many nice methods, such as `issubset` to compare sets with each other:

```
def fivesix(s):
    return set(s).issubset(set('56'))
```

examples:

```
>>> fivesix('123')
False
>>> fivesix('156')
False
>>> fivesix('565')
True
>>> fivesix('5')
True
```

Answer (score 1):

You said this is what you've got so far let's look at it:

```
def numberCheck(string):
    return bool([string == 5 | 6])
```

This isn't really a good way to go about this problem in Python since you are creating a list with logic that checks if 5 or 6 is in string (the way you try to do this does not work but that's a different matter). Then you cast that list as a bool. Since the list will always have a value in it the function always returns true. Non-empty lists are true and empty lists are false in python. So we need to rewrite your code to

1. Return the correct value
2. Check for the presence of 5 or 6 correctly.

Check out this example:

```
def numberCheck(string):
    if string == "":                     # If our string is empty we want to return False
        return False
    five_or_six = set({'5','6'})         # We want every number to be in this domain...
    for character in string:             # So we look at every character in the string
        if character not in five_or_six: # and if it isnt in our accepted set
            return False                 # return False.
    return True                          # if every character is a five or a six return True


print(numberCheck('123'))
print(numberCheck('565'))
```

Comment: ``{'5','6'}`` is already a ``set``. There is no benefit in calling ``set`` on it.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I wanted to make this example kind of painfully obvious but i get your point

Comment: @Upuls263 It's nothing bad, just wanted to point it out. I really like that your answer doesn't just provide the code but presents things a bit.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I'll likely leave it in for clarity then, thank you